# BASH- Run MPlayer if either there are no users on display :0 or if there is more than one argument

Tags: linux, bash

This is the script I currently have-

```
#!/bin/bash
if["$#" == "2" OR who | grep ":0" == ""]
    export DISPLAY=:0
    xset dpms force on
    mplayer -fs $1.mp4
fi
```

It doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rob, Can you be more explicit on what's not working?

Comment: The script just plays the movie even if there is a person on display :0....

Comment: The problem is probably with the ---grep ":0" == ""--- part

Answer (score 3):

You should spend some time reading `man test`, it looks to me like you've got several problems here:

```
if [ "$#" = "2" -o -z "$(who | grep ':0')" ]; then
```

- Notice the space after the `[`.
- Notice the one equal sign for string compare.
- Notice that `-o` is the OR operator.
- Notice the `-z` for testing against the empty string.
- Notice the `$(...)` to execute the who command.
- Notice the space before the `]`.
- However, `who` prints out times and `grep` is going to match a lot of false positives against `HH:MM:SS`.  You may want to improve your match.
- And as other answers note, you should probably check the success of the `$(who|grep)`, rather than testing for empty string output.

In the future, more detail than "it doesn't work" is preferred ;)

Answer (score 1):

In BASH, the test for NULL is -`z` , e.g `if [ -z "$NAME" ]; then ...`. However, you can just as easily use the exit status from grep instead:

```
root@tpost-desktop:/usr/src# who | grep :0
tpost    tty7         2010-05-23 09:16 (:0)
root@tpost-desktop:/usr/src# echo $?
0

root@tpost-desktop:/usr/src# who | grep :123
root@tpost-desktop:/usr/src# echo $?
1
```

If grep did not find what you asked, it will exit with a non-zero status. So you could do something like:

```
who | grep :0 >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
   USING_DISPLAY=1
else
   USING_DISPLAY=0
fi
```

Then test the value of `USING_DISPLAY` , play the movie if its 0

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a space after the `if`, after the `[` and before the ']'.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" == "2" ] || ! who | grep '(.*:0.*)$' > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    export DISPLAY=:0
    xset dpms force on
    mplayer -fs $1.mp4
fi
```