# sh shell code - retrieving command result

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

How can I write a simple shell script that will check if someone using display `:0`?  This does not work:

```
if [ 'who | grep " :0 "' != "" ]
then
    echo "hi"
fi
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the processor arch? What is the OS?

Comment: @Moron: This is an sh (bash?) script, so the OS is unix.

Comment: @BlueRaja: The title said ShellCode, which I presumed was the assembly opcode bytes and so exact OS and processor architecture would matter. The title has been edited now, I see.

Comment: I guess we can let my close vote decay then. Sorry for the confusion mr.web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH- Run MPlayer if either there are no users on display :0 or if there is more than one argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892415/bash-run-mplayer-if-either-there-are-no-users-on-display-0-or-if-there-is-more)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers work, but there's no need to capture the output of the grep (using $() or backtics) for a string comparison, because grep's exit status will indicate success or failure. So you can reduce it to this:

```
if who | grep -q ' :0 '; then
    echo hi
fi
```

Or even simpler:

```
who | grep -q ' :0 ' && echo hi
```

Notes:

- "if" operates on a command or a pipeline of commands.
- Left square bracket is actually a command, another name for 'test'.
- The q option suppresses grep's output (in most versions).
- Instead of invoking who, grep, and test you can just invoke who and grep.
- As another answer noted, you may need to grep for something besides ' :0 ' depending on your system.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
R=$(who | grep " :0 ")
echo $R
if [ "$R" != "" ]; then
    echo "hi"
fi
```

Comment: This should work also.  What's the problem (or are you simply answering your own question)?

Comment: i am answering my own question =]

Answer (score 0):

```
if who | grep " :0 "
then
    echo "hi"
fi
```

Note that the output of who is different for different versions of *who*. For the GNU coreutils 7.4 version of *who* you need *grep '(:0'* instead of *grep " :0 "*